# Laravel 6 PHP 7

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a invoice print in laravel as i did in php using mysql i have been getting a syntax error (syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{')
I know its the previous version of php which i am using but how to write the proper syntax for My route get method

```php
Route::get('/printPreview' , 'PrintController@printPreview');

Route::get('/printPreview' , 'PrintController@printPreview');
```

when the person who i was watching was giving a path from localhost/myproject/public/printPreview the print option was present but when i am doing the method he did the print button was absent

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201528/discussion-on-question-by-faiz-kazi-laravel-6-php-7).

Comment: what do you get if you type `php -v` in console?

Comment: the php version is 7.3.5 @Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong version of PHP. The error you are receiving is because of the use of return type declarations which were introduced in PHP 7. This would make me believe you are using a version of PHP less than 7.

As already said, you can have different versions of PHP on your system. You can be using different versions from the Command Line Interface (CLI) and your web server could be using different versions.

[PHP Manual - New Features in 7.0 - Return Type Declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations)